# there is a fine line between encouraging and discouraging to study languages

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

> There exists a fine line between encouraging and discouraging to study languages.

Is it a correct sentence?

Comment: I suggest you asking it on ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's meaningless, absent any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to say "... discouraging the study of languages" or "... discouraging people/pupils to study languages".